# Offsetting page anchor from fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, offset

I have looked at other posts for this issue but alass none have worked so here i am.

Im trying to make my header(position is fixed) link to a page anchor but when i press the link it goes past the top of the div and the header for it. So to see the entire div including header then you need to scroll up.

I have got a [Fiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/pp9dg/25/)

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
margin: 130px auto;
padding: 0;
background-color: aliceblue;}
```

Comment: What if you removed the margin from the wrapper and added a padding-top of 200px?

Comment: This would work if only it didn't leave large amounts of whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use CSS. Just make standalone hidden anchor elements and clip them the height of your header.

Here is the anchor class I used:

```
a.anchor {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 top: -250px;
 visibility: hidden;
    height:0px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**(I only did the first few links): http://jsfiddle.net/pp9dg/29/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pp9dg/28/

It uses jquery which offsets the anchor point by 200px.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 200);
});
```

Comment: When i press on the link twice it redirects to below the header of the given div. Is there a way to fix that.